# XGBoost: how to interpret these results?

Tags: classification, python

I'm using XGBoost package (under Python) on a Kaggle set.

I'm running the following code

```
import xgboost as xgb
data_train   = np.array(traindata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels_train = np.array(traindata['Category'].cat.codes)

data_valid   = np.array(validdata.drop('Category',axis=1))
labels_valid = np.array(validdata['Category'].astype('category').cat.codes)

weights_train = np.ones(len(labels_train))
weights_valid  = np.ones(len(labels_valid ))

dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data_train, label=labels_train,weight = weights_train)
dvalid  = xgb.DMatrix( data_valid , label=labels_valid ,weight = weights_valid )




param_train = {'bst:max_depth':5, 'bst:eta':0.3, # eta [default=0.3]
         #'min_child_weight':1,'gamma':0,'subsample':1,'colsample_bytree':1,'scale_pos_weight':0, # default
         # max_delta_step:0 # default
         'min_child_weight':5,'scale_pos_weight':0, 'max_delta_step':2,'lambda':2,
         'subsample':0.8,'colsample_bytree':0.8,
         'silent':1, 'objective':'multi:softprob','eval_metric':'mlogloss','num_class':39,'nthread':4,
         'evals_result':['eval_metric'],'evallist': [(dtrain,'train'),(dvalid,'eval')]}

param_CV = {'bst:max_depth':5, 'bst:eta':0.3,        
         'min_child_weight':5,'scale_pos_weight':0, 'max_delta_step':2,'lambda':2,
         'subsample':0.8,'colsample_bytree':0.8,
         'silent':1, 'objective':'multi:softprob','eval_metric':'mlogloss','num_class':39,'nthread':4,
         'evals_result':['eval_metric'],
         'verbose_eval':True}

evallist  = [(dtrain,'train'),(dvalid,'eval')] # if there is a validation set
# evallist  = [(dtrain,'train')]                   # if there is no validation set

num_round = 100

bst = xgb.train( param_train, dtrain, num_round, evallist,early_stopping_rounds=5 ) # early_stopping_rounds=10 # when there is a validation set

res=xgb.cv(param_CV,dtrain=dtrain,num_boost_round=num_round,nfold = 5,early_stopping_rounds=5)
```

so the params are the same, except that in CV i don't need to print the evallist ? (its not an accepted parameter i think ?)

then here is what i get

```
> Will train until eval error hasn't decreased in 5 rounds.
> [0]   train-mlogloss:3.222158 eval-mlogloss:3.331301
> [1]   train-mlogloss:2.884756 eval-mlogloss:3.097502
> [2]   train-mlogloss:2.632060 eval-mlogloss:2.945249
> [3]   train-mlogloss:2.470736 eval-mlogloss:2.850051
> [4]   train-mlogloss:2.358537 eval-mlogloss:2.791360
> [5]   train-mlogloss:2.278458 eval-mlogloss:2.753927
> [6]   train-mlogloss:2.214835 eval-mlogloss:2.728683
> [7]   train-mlogloss:2.164496 eval-mlogloss:2.712738
> [8]   train-mlogloss:2.123897 eval-mlogloss:2.702676
> [9]   train-mlogloss:2.091214 eval-mlogloss:2.694672
> [10]  train-mlogloss:2.064233 eval-mlogloss:2.689833
> [11]  train-mlogloss:2.040527 eval-mlogloss:2.690605
> [12]  train-mlogloss:2.020167 eval-mlogloss:2.693260
> [13]  train-mlogloss:2.003255 eval-mlogloss:2.697917
> [14]  train-mlogloss:1.988390 eval-mlogloss:2.704585
> [15]  train-mlogloss:1.975163 eval-mlogloss:2.712515 Stopping. Best
> iteration: [10]   train-mlogloss:2.064233 eval-mlogloss:2.689833

res

    test-mlogloss-mean  test-mlogloss-std   train-mlogloss-mean train-mlogloss-std
0   3.249529    0.011871    3.201333    0.002639
1   2.929290    0.016930    2.829826    0.006743
2   2.696570    0.023819    2.546634    0.008640
3   2.542200    0.030709    2.347780    0.008460
4   2.440506    0.034024    2.203404    0.009297
5   2.368498    0.033255    2.095443    0.010717
6   2.311877    0.034071    2.006866    0.010142
7   2.270071    0.034105    1.933655    0.010083
8   2.237238    0.037012    1.872254    0.009957
9   2.211688    0.038777    1.819701    0.008550
10  2.190893    0.038745    1.774208    0.009258
11  2.173965    0.037626    1.732723    0.008969
12  2.159105    0.038843    1.694437    0.009346
13  2.148262    0.039140    1.660285    0.008647
14  2.139713    0.039134    1.628401    0.007815
15  2.133940    0.040289    1.601097    0.007548
16  2.129378    0.040396    1.575236    0.006340
17  2.127329    0.041668    1.551052    0.008037
18  2.125965    0.041890    1.525768    0.007868
19  2.124177    0.042267    1.504649    0.008013
20  2.123374    0.042020    1.483685    0.009100
```

I don't understand why the result in the single run has a much higher logloss (eval-mlogloss 2.689) than in the CV run (test-mlogloss 2.123) while i'm running it on the same set right and same parameters right ?

also why are there 20 lines in res ? i specified 5 folders, but is the CV always running 20 times ? (this 20 doesn't seem to be a parameter and i haven't seen this number in any doc ?)

thank you

Comment: You should see if this is a stable phenomena.  i.e., run an experiment where you draw a random testing data set, tune with cross validation on the rest, then score the final model on your test set.  Do this over and over many times.  You may have just, by chance, drawn a weird test set, and find that averaged over many test sets, the phenomena disappears.

Answer (score 1):

XGBoost shows the performance in every iteration (in your example, 100 iterations will have 100 lines in the training.), i.e., it shows the performance during the training process but not showing you the final results. You can turn off the verbose mode to have a more clear view.

```
xgboost(param=param,data=x,label=y, nrounds=n_iter, verbose = F)
```

In addition, keep in mind

1. Anything can happen in testing set
2. Training loss will decrease with more iterations

Comment: I'm using the same set as you can see. but on the single run, on the validation data set, (a set different from the training set, but extracted randomly from the initial set), i have a test-eval logloss of 2.689.
while on the CV, I have as low as  2.123 logloss only. a huge difference. I don't understand why